# When comparing 2 strings ignore number in middle of those strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am comparing a two variable values in Jquery,but here I need to ignore numbers between them.
code like below:

```
var value1=Earn a score greater than or equal to 3 points for assignment certifictaion Issue Testing ;

var value2=Earn a score greater than or equal to 6 points for assignment certifictaion Issue Testing ;
```

When compare both the string using j query, i want compare irrespective of numbers present in middle of both the strings

Comment: You could compare two auxiliary strings without the number in the middle (a simple `replace()` call can remove the numbers from the strings).

Comment: value1.replace(/\d/g, "") is value1 sans digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just replace all numbers with empty spaces? and afterwords compare the two strings?

```
var value1 = "Earn a score greater than or equal to 3 points for assignment certifictaion Issue Testing";
var value2= "Earn a score greater than or equal to 61 points for assignment certifictaion Issue Testing";

var result = value1.replace(/\d/g, "") === value2.replace(/\d/g, "");
alert(result)
```